# Update an Indexed View "Online"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, materialized-view, online-operations

Say I have an indexed view that looks like this:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.MyIndexedView WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
    SELECT ord.SomeColumn, COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count
    FROM dbo.Ordered ord
    WHERE ord.CreatedWhen >  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-11-01', 121)
    GROUP BY ord.SomeColumn
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_MyIndexedView] ON dbo.MyIndexedView (SomeColumn)
GO
```

If I change the date time value in this view (say to '2014-11-01') then the clustered index needs to be regenerated.

**Is there a way to have the existing view and index stay in effect until the new one is totally built and then have them swap?**  Similar to `Online=On`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. First, create a couple of spare schemas:

```
CREATE SCHEMA HoldingTank AUTHORIZATION dbo;
CREATE SCHEMA Swapper AUTHORIZATION dbo;
```

Now, when it's time to refresh the view and change the filter predicate, create it in the `HoldingTank` schema:

```
CREATE VIEW HoldingTank.MyIndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT ...
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_MyIndexedView]
ON HoldingTank.MyIndexedView(SomeColumn);
```

Now, start a transaction, and swap the objects.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  ALTER SCHEMA Swapper TRANSFER dbo.MyIndexedView;
  ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER HoldingTank.MyIndexedView;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Then at a later time you can simply drop the old copy of the view from `Swapper`:

```
DROP VIEW Swapper.MyIndexedView;
```

I go into more detail about this solution in these blog posts:

- [T-SQL Tuesday #33 : Trick Shots : Schema Switch-A-Roo](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo)
- [Schema Switch-A-Roo : Part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)